# Missing Comma in SQL Command Oracle VM

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am getting an error which says Missing comma at line 5. Can someone help :(

```
Insert into Department values(
'Computer',
Faculty_n(
Faculty_t('Allan', Student_n(Student_t(PhD_v('David','Henry'), Masters_v('Emily','James','Kevin')))),
Faculty_t('Terry', Student_n(Student_t(PhD_v('Maria'), Masters_v('Alvi','Sandy')))));
```

For reference:

```
create type PhD_v as varray(4) of varchar(10);
/
create type Masters_v as varray(6) of varchar(10);
/
create type Student_t as object(
PhD PhD_v,
Masters Masters_v);
/
create type Student_n as table of Student_t;
/
create type Faculty_t as object(
Name Varchar(10),
Students Student_n);
/
create type Faculty_n as table of Faculty_t;
/
create table Department(
Name Varchar(10),
Faculty Faculty_n)
nested table Faculty store as Faculty_tb(
nested table Students store as Student_tb);
```

Not sure what the problem is, hopefully someone can guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a comma, but - closing bracket *is* missing at the very end.

```
INSERT INTO Department
        VALUES (
                  'Computer',
                  Faculty_n (
                     Faculty_t (
                        'Allan',
                        Student_n (
                           Student_t (PhD_v ('David', 'Henry'),
                                      Masters_v ('Emily', 'James', 'Kevin')))),
                     Faculty_t (
                        'Terry',
                        Student_n (
                           Student_t (PhD_v ('Maria'),
                                      Masters_v ('Alvi', 'Sandy'))))));
```